# Links are not working when files are uploaded on server

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

admin side panel dropdown links are not working. I am working on project where I have an admin panel with side panel which includes links and dropdown elements. Single links without dropdown are working but dropdown is not opening and showing other li elements. It's working fine on localhost, but it's causing a problem when uploaded to the server.

Comment: Have you checked your console? You might spot errors if any

Answer (score 1):

**If you use various JavaScript/CSS Files, try to check if every file is in the same path as in the HTML code. Try testing the navbar element on a codepen so you can find the issue more easily.**

**Make sure that JQuery is first, then the Bootstrap script. Lookup that you don't have any duplicated bootstrap scripts. You should also add bootstrap.bundle.js or add popper.js so the dropdown can work.**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[**Check this codepen with a example**](https://codepen.io/kalmix/pen/WNOYrme)

Comment: The best advice would be they have a look on the console. This would point to the issue. Instead of guessing

Comment: I checked my code and found that it was problem due to bootstrap cdn. it is http and hence it showed no problem on localhost but as my website is secure means https when i uploaded files on server it started throwing errors and links were not working. I replaced http with https in bootstrap links in head. and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I checked my code and found that it was problem due to bootstrap cdn. it is http and hence it showed no problem on localhost but as my website is secure means https when i uploaded files on server it started throwing errors and links were not working. I replaced http with https in bootstrap links in head. and now it is working fine.